# Keywords Ranking

Tags: ranking, text-mining

I have a list of keywords taken from 95 documents. I'd like to rank their importance, but I have only the number of documents in which the keywords appear and the maximum frequency of a keyword among all the documents. I'm looking for a ranking formula that could help. At the moment I'm using **IDF**, but I'd like to know if there is any better formula.

Answer (score 1):

word frequency is already done by listing the most important words in English ( and many other langs ) by [Wikitionary Frequency Lists](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aFrequency_lists) which has many type of lists based on the [most important and top words](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aFrequency_lists#Top_English_words_lists), besides the [TV and Movies most frequent words](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aFrequency_lists#TV_and_movie_scripts) and many others.

If you like to do some algorithm based on word ranking I would suggest you don't go far away from 
[TF-IDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf)

and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_indexing) you can find the Latent semantic indexing algorithm which might me an asset for you.

Hope that is what you needed.

Answer (score 1):

TF-IDF is definitely a good base and easy to implement.

It is also really common to add other bias such as the position of your terms inside your documents; a term occurring at the beginning of a document, or better, in its title tends to be more relevant than the ones occurring in the middle or at the end.

But you have to keep in mind that choosing an algorithm and its bias also depends on the nature of your documents. For instance, long documents (e.g. research papers or books) would need a position bias, but not necessarily news articles. Same thing for the "IDF" measure, it has to be computed on a large corpus of documents with similar type of content than your documents. You don't want to have a relevancy score computed on a "TV and Movies" corpus if for instance your documents are research papers about semi-conductors.

My two cents.